# Error when trying to load the interceptors dynamically in Spring Security

Tags: spring-security, interceptor

I have configured spring security for generate interceptors dynamcally from DB. I have guide [here](http://wp.misschara.com/). When I try to access a home page from login page get the following error:

```
An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
```

This error happen in the class AbstractSecurityInterceptor in the following lines (I did debugging):

```
if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            credentialsNotFound(messages.getMessage("AbstractSecurityInterceptor.authenticationNotFound",
                    "An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext"), object, attributes);
        }
```

This is log:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
    org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.credentialsNotFound(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:339)
    org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:198)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
```

This is [link](http://pastebin.com/i5UQG0AJ) of my file configuration of Spring Security

I don't understand because happen this error, user with to login on in my app have SYS_ADMIN role. This role is authorized to access to homepage...

I've debugged and checked that class InterceptorApplicationService (This class implements interface FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource) return SYS_ADMN role and list of roles in the methods getAttributes and getAllConfigAttributes respectively

Comment: when the errors is coming? ie the page requested

Comment: When I try to login. I just edit the question to explain in more detail the problem

Comment: I've edited my question for to make it more detalied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. Here is [post](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?135714-AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException-An-Authentication-object-was-not-found-in)

Comment: It has been 8 years but can you share the answer? The link is not accessible anymore..